# How to add a new module in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm just starting with ZF2. I installed ZF2, created the VirtualHost and I'm able see the welcome page. Then I added a new module in the module directory and then added the module name in the application.config.php but every time it says

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /application was not found on this server.

ZF2 comes with a default module called application, so if I hit the URL like "virtuaHostName/application" then also it should show the welcome page right? but I'm seeing that same "Not found" message.

Answer (score 1):

Do not misinterpret `ModuleNames` for `RouteNames`. If you take a look inside `module.config.php` you'll see an array in the following syntax:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        '$routeName' => array(
            // $routeParams 
        )
    )
)
```

In this case `$routeName` of course always will be a string that defines the NAME of a route. To know which URL is attached to that route, you got to look at the `$routeParams`. This usually looks like the following:

```
'type' => '$routeType',
'options' => array(
    'route' => '$theRoute'
)
```

The `$routeType` always is a string, too. Here people usually add one of the shortnames for the routetype that are defined [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-regex) (scroll up a little). Alternatively the full classname to the specific route could be given, too.

Inside the `options` array you'd define the options that a route needs. One will always be `route`, as this is the matching criteria for a route. Following example:

```
'route' => '/test'
Matching URL: http://myproject.dev/test
```

There's one catch however and that is child-routes. When there are child-routes, the `route` option gets attached to it's parent routes. So for example:

```
'route' => '/test'   // <- This is the PARENT Route
'route' => '/foobar' // -< This is the CHILD Route
Matching URL: http://myproject.dev/test/foobar
```

Hope this helps you out a little with understanding the framework routing. More information can always be gathered from the [official Documentation of Zend\Mvc\Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#)

Comment: Also make sure that you register your module controller in module.config.*(php)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your time. So far I have created one or two module and those modules are working fine, then i setup another environment for zf2 , I copied the same module in module directory of new environment. So I just need to register the module name in the application.config.php because configuration inside the module was working properly. So that's where am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

To add any new module you need to define new module name in follwing array in
     application.config.php file in config folder. Suppose you need to add new module 'Admin'. You 
     can set that here as follows:

```
return array(
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'Admin',
),
```

Note: Application is the default module.

Answer (score 0):

Add the module name in application.config.php then add the route in module.config.php. Of couse you have to add the invoke controller in "invokables" array in module.config.php

Comment: application.config.php  file location please??

Answer (score 0):

To add/create any new module in zend framework 2. it provide ZFTool to do this worked by a simple some steps.

1) download ZFTool to official site of zend framework.
2) extract it in root folder of you project.
3) access it by command by(path to project>php zftool/zf.php create module module name project path)

you can get more detail on

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BNg2zPzEmI&index=5&list=PLMoDvYQTYOX3C1WZvNVLm7u3YTRvR5Zhs